# How to put Admob ad in RecyclerView

Tags: android, admob, android-recyclerview

I'm try to implenent Admob ad in a RecyclerView. I tried a lot of examples but not issue.
I want to insert one ad between 8 items of my RecyclerView

```
public class StarRVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StarRVViewHolder>{
private Context c;
private ArrayList<Questions> questionEntries;
Questions qe;
StarRVViewHolder holderClass;
String answerCount=null,likes;
public StarRVAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Questions> questionEntries,Questions qe) {
    this.c = c;
    this.qe = qe;
    this.questionEntries = questionEntries;
}
@Override
public StarRVViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.actu_list_item,parent,false);
    return new StarRVViewHolder(v,c);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final StarRVViewHolder holder, int position) {
     qe = (Questions)this.getItem(position);
    holder.setDate(qe.getQuestion_date());
    holder.setContent(qe.getQuestion_content());
    holder.setImg(qe.getImgUrl());
    holder.setTitle(qe.getQuestion_title());
    holder.setAsker(qe.getQuestion_username());
    holder.setNumberOfAnswer(getAnswers());
    holder.setNumberOfLikes(getLikeksCount());
    Toast.makeText(c,qe.question_title,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return questionEntries.size();
}
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return questionEntries.get(position);
}
```

}
This is my Asdapter class. Thanks

Comment: Which type of ad? `Banner` or?

Comment: I want to implement banner Ad

Comment: Ads which are intended to be between rows of recyclerview are native ads. Currently they are in limited beta. And implementation `Banner` ads between rows I think violates Admobs terms of use.

Comment: Thak you @Yupi. But how can i make native ads easily (the simplest way)

Comment: As I wrote native ads are in beta. Check on this link how can you get IDs for native ads: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native-advanced